# Jsoup Scraping HTML dynamic content

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I'm new to Jsoup and I have been trying to create a small code that gets the name of the items in a steam inventory using Jsoup.

```
public Element getItem(String user) throws IOException{
    Document doc;

    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://steamcommunity.com/id/"+user+"/inventory").get();
    Element element = doc.getElementsByClass("hover_item_name").first();
    return element;
}
```

this methods returns:

```
<h1 class="hover_item_name" id="iteminfo0_item_name"></h1>
```

and I want the information beetwen the "h1" labels which is generated when you click on a specific window.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean "<h1>XYZ</h1>" -> "XYZ" ?

Comment: yeah, i want that "XYZ" but its generated when you click a specific window

Comment: See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50189638/8583692).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.select(String cssQuery)` method:

`doc.select("h1")` gives you all `h1` `Elements`.
If you need the actual Text in these tags use the `.text()` for each `Element`.
If you need a attribute like `class` or `id` use `.attr(String attributeKey)` on a `Element` eg:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("hover_item_name").first().attr("id")
```

gives you `"iteminfo0_item_name"`

But if you need to perform clicks on a website you can't do that with JSoup, hence JSoup is a HTML parser and not a browser alternative. Jsoup can't handle dynamic content.

But what you could do is, firstly scrape the relevant data in your `h1` tags and then send a new `.post()` [request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012969/6242846), respectively an [ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27723314/6242846)

If you rather want a real webdriver, have a look at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp).

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I want to handle dynamic content so i think ill be using another method different from Jsoup

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` and return a `String`, i.e.:

```
public String getItem(String user) throws IOException{
    Document doc;
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://steamcommunity.com/id/"+user+"/inventory").get();
    Element element = doc.getElementsByClass("hover_item_name").first();
    String text = element.text();
    return text;
}
```