# web scraping jsoup java unable to scrape full information

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have an information to be scraped from a website. I could scrape it. But not all the information is being scraped. There is so much of data loss. The following images helps you further to understand :
[image: This is the data which I want to scrape :]

I used Jsoup, connected it to URL and then extracted this particular data using the following code :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.awattar.com/tariffs/hourly#").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
Elements durationCycle = doc.select("g.x.axis g.tick text");
```

But in the result, I couldn't find any of that related information at all. So I printed the whole document from the URL and it shows the following :
[image: Scrapped data and full information missing]

I could see the information when I download the page and read it as an input file but not when I connect directly to URL. But I want to connect it to URL. Is there any suggestion?

I hope my question is understandable. Let me know in case if it is not explanatory.

Comment: The website is probably running javascript and loading content dynamically. Your browser does execute JS, your scraper does not.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Yes that is true.. Website is running Javascript and loading content dynamically. Is there any possible way how to scrape this? What can I use?

Comment: you can use Selenium WebDriver as your browser engine and your scraper, or you can use Selenium only as your browser and Jsoup as your scraper. https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720839/web-scrapping-with-jsoup-and-selenium

Comment: See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50189638/8583692).

Answer (score 0):

There is a request body limitation in Jsoup. you should use the maxBodySize parameter:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.awattar.com/tariffs/hourly#").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").maxBodySize(0).get();
```

"0" is no limit.